# Android button with transperent png image and background colour

Tags: java, android, button, imagebutton

I need a button with foreground transparent image and background color. So have use this code. The background color is going outside of the image. I need the button with the same size of the image.

Depending on the user interaction i have to change the foreground image and background color. I want add the image and background color separately so that i can change one of them at minimum cost. I have to use a lot of button in this UI so it will be done in java code.

```
layout = new TableLayout(this);
layout.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(8,7));
TableRow row2 = new TableRow(this);
buttonPlayer1 = new ImageButton(this);
buttonPlayer1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blankc4));
buttonPlayer1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
row2.addView(buttonPlayer1);
layout.addView(row2);
```

Comment: try to use selector if you want to change the behavour of your button on diiferent state: clicked,focused, normal

Answer (score 1):

If your only problem is that button background color is going outsize image and you need button size to be same as image size then get image **Height** and **Width** using  `getHeight()` & `getWidth()` methods on image object and use these values to make the **Button size** same as **Image size** using `setHeight()` & `setWidth()` methods respectively on button object.

### Sample Code with LinearLayout:

---

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout btnLO = new LinearLayout(this);    
        btnLO.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        ImageButton i1 = new ImageButton(this);
        i1.setBackgroundColor(color.background_dark);
        i1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rana));   
        btnLO.addView(i1, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));                      
  //    btnLO.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);     
        this.addContentView(btnLO, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
    }
```

Comment: I have tried setHeight() & setWidth() also. But there is no method for **ImageButton** like this. I have tried setMaxHeight() and setMaxWidth() also. but it don't give the correct output.

Comment: @Sudeepta I got the solution, use `row2.addView(buttonPlayer1,new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
               LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));` in place of `row2.addView(buttonPlayer1);` then your **imagebutton** will take the size of the given image. This will solve your problem.You can also manually define imagebutton size like `row2.addView(buttonPlayer1,new LayoutParams(300,
               300));`.Finally, you should have checked with setMinimumHeight and width methods :)

Comment: i have tested above but when i use LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT or LayoutParams(100, 100)) it display nothing. Another amazing thing is when i use row2.addView(buttonPlayer1); after setMinimumHeight and width, getHeight() and  width return 0 but in the button action it return 100 and 103.

Comment: Sonds interesting, I checked by adding imagebutton to LinearLayout (you can check it from my edited answer). Why is **layout** has parameter like 8,7 and how are you attaching this?

Comment: In main code layout parameter will be 8,7. For LinearLayout I got it before. It works interestingly in table layout if i use xml for ui.